# picker wheel that only appears when selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I have a view controller that displays various `UITextfield`s to edit information. For one `UITextfield` I need a picker wheel to select predefined statuses.

Problem is I don't have enough space to integrate a picker wheel, is there a possibility to make it appear only when the text box is selected?

Comment: you need to call your UIpickerview in `- (BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView` look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077258/how-to-show-uipickerview-when-selecting-uitextfield

Comment: thanks that works. Can you post a answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the `UIPickerView` as the `UITextField`'s `inputView`.

This will ensure that the picker is shown automatically when the text field gets focus, and hides it when lost.

E.g.

```
myTextField.inputView = self.myPickerView;
```

See the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006888-CH3-SW53) on this property.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your "picker wheel" is a UIView, just hook up your controller as the UITextField's delegate and implement the following:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
   self.pickerWheel.hidden = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call your UIPicker in `(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:`

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{


    if (textField==self.yourtextfield) {
         //call your wheel in here 
    }
}
```

Look at 
[How to Show UIPickerView when selecting UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077258/how-to-show-uipickerview-when-selecting-uitextfield)