# How to prevent Keyboard popping up when i touched textfield

Tags: ios

i have three text fields.for one of them i Don't want to popping up keyboard.instead of keyboard UIPicker has to be popup. help me how to get.

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set the inputView value of a UITextField to point to a picker, that picker will be loaded when someone selects that UITextField. Make sure you configure your picker first, and then set the inputView value of your UITextField like shown in the code below. Now iOS will handle everything else and make sure to show the picker.

```
UIPickerView *myPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
//myPickerView configuration here...
myTextField.inputView = myPickerView;
```

refers to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7077482/2800736)

Comment: Maybe a little explanation on what happens, but this is the right solution.